# How to stop Google Analytics default query timeout (60 seconds I believe)

Tags: java, google-analytics, timeout, google-analytics-api

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration, an open source ETL/ data transfer tool.

The tool is built on java and uses a service account & key file to make requests to the Google Analytics API.

Problem is --- the Google Analytics API seems to have a default server side timeout of exactly 60 seconds before it stops and errors out.

Now, I did come across the following info to extend the timeout:

```
 private HttpRequestInitializer setHttpTimeout(final HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer) {
  return new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
      requestInitializer.initialize(httpRequest);
      httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes connect timeout
      httpRequest.setReadTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes read timeout
    }
  };

GoogleCredential credential = ....

final Analytics analytics = Analytics.builder(new NetHttpTransport(), jsonFactory, setHttpTimeout(credential)).build();
```

Only problem is that I'm not exactly sure how to implement this in conjunction with the 3rd party tool PDI --- I can execute a stand alone Java code - but I'm not exactly sure if the above script will permanently increase the timeout duration for a given account, or only for the session.

Is there any simple way to extend the timeout for Google Analytics for an account without necessarily executing complicated code?

If not, how exactly do I use the above code snippet?

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to fetch? And which API are you using? Also, I do not think GA will take too much time to response i.e. more than 60 seconds. This should be code related issue.

Comment: You can easily go over 60 seconds in the Google Analytics API. Because you can quickly get very granular. For instance, taking a month worth of 'pageview' data by destination page is fine. However even taking a few days worth of "previous page -> destination page" combo (we have 1000 different pages about) ... goes from 1,000 values per day ... to 1,000,000 values per day. We have so many custom URL parameters on our website to ... I'm not sure if there's a way to filter these out pre-fetch from the API. Point is ... easily can go over 60 seconds ... I need to change the timeout in GA.

Comment: Can you check on [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) how much time API is taking to response?

Comment: The Query Explorer is significantly faster. Though it may have been optimized by Google a great deal - and also may not be Java based, like Pentaho PDI ETL tool is. Unless I want to create my own script from scratch, the fetch time is what it is. Nevertheless, optimizing the fetch time is a bit different from effectively removing the timeout parameter, even though it would also solve the problem.